# Catching Xerneas in Pokemon X?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Does anybody know where I can catch Xerneas in *Pokemon X*? I need to find Xerneas but I don't know where.

Comment: Just play the game! You will get it near the end of the main story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep following the the story line until you get to [Team Flare's Secret HQ](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Team_Flare_Secret_HQ). After fighting a number of Team Flare trainers, you will be forced to face off against the game's version specific legendary (Xerneas in your case). The fight will repeat until you successfully capture it. Do not worry if your PC boxes are all full, the 31st box will not unlock until the legendary is caught, ensuring you have enough room for it.

Comment: Make sure that once you made it to the HQ that your pokemon are ready for the many battles that will take place